# Wrap ever 1 component into a div and display it in a grid column

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Hello I'm kinda noob with react and I don't know how to slice every 1 item into a new div and then display it on the page with `grid grid-cols-2 gap-4` tailwindcss styling, so I'd like to have 2 colums and 2 items in each row. Right now even I apply this tailwindcss there is 1 column and every 1 item is on a new row ;/ So I got to slice every one `item.title`, `item.coverImage.url` in a new div?

```
export default function BlogPage({ items }) {
  console.log(items);
  return (
    <div className="max-w-lg mx-auto">
      {items?.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.slug} className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
          <Link href={`/portfolio/${item.slug}`}>
            <div>
              <a>
                {item.title}
                <Image
                  src={item.coverImage.url}
                  height={item.coverImage.height}
                  width={item.coverImage.width}
                />
              </a>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: bubuq3 also wants this which is not stated in the question “ Thank you for your reply :) Kinda works, but only for 2 elements in a row. If I'd like to have more there is no way e.g. if I set grid-cols-4 and apply max-w-5xl mx-auto to the main div. There must be a problem with margin or what? Even If I set max-full-w there is only 2 elements in a row. and not centered mx-auto ;/”

Comment: Ok, just works. I need to change to `col-span-4` and `grid-cols-4`. Thank you :) Why did you delete your answer? You helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add class col-span-1 to the div to explicitly tell how much column-span it needs to occupy.

```
export default function BlogPage({ items }) {
  console.log(items);
  return (
    <div className="max-w-lg mx-auto">
      {items?.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.slug} className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
          <Link href={`/portfolio/${item.slug}`}>
            <div className="col-span-1">
              <a>
                {item.title}
                <Image
                  src={item.coverImage.url}
                  height={item.coverImage.height}
                  width={item.coverImage.width}
                />
              </a>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) Kinda works, but only for 2 elements in a row. If I'd like to have more there is no way e.g. if I set grid-cols-4 and apply max-w-5xl mx-auto to the main div. There must be a problem with margin or what? Even If I set max-full-w there is only 2 elements in a row. and not centered mx-auto ;/